# Can I bring my peanuts to Russia, or does the Russian import ban/sanctions apply to travellers personal items?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, russia

There is currently (2019-07-18) a Russian import ban on certain EU products in force.  See [Russian import ban on EU products, European Commission](https://ec.europa.eu/food/safety/international_affairs/eu_russia/russian_import_ban_eu_products_en).

Does this import ban apply to all circumstances, or is it specifically about commercial imports?  For example, if I have some peanuts, raisins, or oats with me on the train, can I bring this into Russia or is it *de jure* also subject to the ban?  If it is *de jure* banned, how is the *de facto* enforcement?  Will they take away my peanuts leaving me with nothing to snack for the rest of my journey?  I have no clue what the Combined Nomenclature (CN) code of my food products might be.

Comment: I'm not making this an answer as I can't tell you anything about the *de jure* status, and can only offer an anecdotal response to the *de facto* status, but: based on first-hand (two trips to Russia in the last year) and second-hand (my fiancee currently lives in Moscow and travels regularly) experience there's no enforcement. On a trip to Barcelona earlier this year my fiancee picked up some food products to take back home. When I asked if she'd actually be allowed to take them into Russia her response was simply to burst out laughing at the idea that there'd be any attempt to enforce this.

Comment: So far, the ban has only applied to commercial imports. If it is to change and when, nobody knows. There are discussions about banning all (not only EU-sourced) personal imports of meats and produce due to quarantine reasons.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @ach Are peanuts produce?  I thought produce referred to fresh products such as fresh fruits, vegetables, dairy.

Comment: Well, one has to analyze the law - if and when it is passed. Usually, this applies to unprocessed stuff, because processed stuff is usually considered safe. However, given the level of paranoia in the ruling gang, who knows.

Comment: I have had the same experience as @ChrisH, I am originally from Russia and travel there frequently. I have brought all sorts of things across the border and they never even asked.

Comment: Russian authorities hardly check your luggage when you enter. I have been stopped only once, out of four visits, and they just wanted to see how much cash I was bringing in. As long as your Euro peanuts aren't for commercial import (resale?) then you should be fine. Russians wont care about your peanuts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be fine. I know many people who brought jams, coffee, nuts, chocolate and other foods into Russia. No problem at all. Barely enforcing or checking your luggage. Unless you act suspicious to them.

Comment: Also, it may depend on amount of stuff you're trying to bring. More you have, more suspicious it would be.

Comment: I agree, OP will be fine. They're usually more interested in any excessive amounts of cash, drugs or luxury items (jewelry, fur coats, etc). I've never seen anybody checked for food (in Moscow airports).